# Angular2 - Webpi GET call returns 405

Tags: angular, get

I'm trying to get response from this webapi:

https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base=EUR&symbols=USD,CAD

I just have to call it directly by using an http GET...

As you can see, if you hit the link using a browser, it works, but If I try
to call it in Angular2 I get 405 error...

This is the code:

```
  Get_ExchangeRate_FromApi(): Observable<ApiExchangeRateResponse> {
    var url = "https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base=EUR&symbols=USD,CAD";

    var headers = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({

      })
    });

    return this.http.get(url, headers)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch();
  }
```

How can i Fix it ?

Comment: Did you try comparing a successful request (via the browser) to an unsuccessful one, using Chrome DevTools or a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: Yes I did it, the headers seems to be the same...

Comment: Hmm. Is everything else the same? Is there a forum or documentation for this web service?

Comment: Unable to reproduce it Check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asho6u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

### Write this code in your service  file :

---

```
private url:String =   "https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latestbase=EUR&symbols=USD,CAD";

 Get_ExchangeRate_FromApi(){
 return this.http.get(this.url)
 .map((response:Response) => response.json());
 }
```

---

### In your component:

```
this.Serviceobject.GetJson()
           .subscribe(
              data => {
                  this.getResponseVariable = data
              },
              error => alert(error),
              () => console.log(this.getLoginRes)
            );
```

Just try this